# Wireless is not working on Toshiba C - 850 13g

Tags: wireless, 12.10

First of all, I have to say that I am a new user of Ubuntu and I am not familiar with it at all... After installing Ubuntu 12.10 it would not recognise the wireless networks available... How do I fix this?

After trying the Wireless troubleshooting the results are:

1. The device is on!
2. The output of the terminal `lshw -C network` is :

   ```
   *-network UNCLAIMED     
      description: Network controller
      product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
      vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
      version: 00
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
      configuration: latency=0
      resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:92400000-92403fff
   *-network
      description: Ethernet interface
      product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
      vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
      logical name: eth0
      version: 05
      serial: 4c:72:b9:83:7b:1e
      size: 100Mbit/s
      capacity: 100Mbit/s
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet
                    physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
      configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169   
                     driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full 
                     firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw 
                     ip=192.168.10.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes 
                     port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
      resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90004000-90004fff   
                 memory:90000000-90003fff
   ```
3. I tried with no success to find the windows driver, so I cannot use the windows wireless drivers.
4. The output of the terminal `iwconfig` is :

   ```
     eth0      no wireless extensions.
     lo        no wireless extensions.
   ```
5. The output of `ifconfig` is:

   ```
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:72:b9:83:7b:1e  
       inet addr:192.168.10.17  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
       inet6 addr: fe80::4e72:b9ff:fe83:7b1e/64 Scope:Link
       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
       RX packets:2705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:2253 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
       RX bytes:2479055 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:257036 (257.0 KB)

   lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
       inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
       inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
       RX packets:548 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:548 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
       RX bytes:49814 (49.8 KB)  TX bytes:49814 (49.8 KB)
   ```
6. The output of the terminal `ping -c3 85.190.27.2` is :

   ```
   PING 85.190.27.2 (85.190.27.2) 56(84) bytes of data.

   --- 85.190.27.2 ping statistics ---
   3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2014ms
   ```
7. The output of the terminal `ping www.ubuntu.com` is:

   ```
   64 bytes from avocado.canonical.com (91.189.90.40): 
       icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=112 ms
   ```

   a thousand times
8. No output with the terminal `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/aliases` !!

I must be doing something ....

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to Ubuntu I request you to go through the Ubuntu Official Documentation [Wireless troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/troubleshooting-wireless.html)

Comment: I tried and nothing has changed! Updated the upper!